# Allow us to edit tags on migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, edits

The title should explain it.  An example of why this should be allowed is evident in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068984/how-do-you-manage-mssql-2000-2005-patches-closed

Currently it's the *only* question on StackOverflow tagged 'mssql', and we cannot remove that tag.  As a consequence, the mssql tag is still active for new users with low rep.

Comment: Some kind moderator has been in and edited the tags

Comment: Yes, but that same moderator now has two `sql-server` tags on it, which I would have hoped would be impossible.

Comment: What was the outcome of this, Joel?  Tags on migrated questions can only be merged, not removed?

Comment: The outcome was "flag it for a ♦ moderator to fix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, there aren't any <kbd>mssql</kbd> questions ;-p

```
updating post history, 26 rows affected
updating posts, 19 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [sql-server] and [mssql] complete!
```

The locking etc is there to prevent it become re-opened, and for the low volume that this happens, I suspect that (for now at least) MSO or moderator flags would work fine. It isn't (IMO) worth the time to think of a "better" approach, let alone implement it...

Comment: Good enough  ;)

Comment: Marc, is this a one-time thing, or may I relax my vigilance? :-)

Comment: AFAIK, there have been no changes to prevent tags being re-created. Out of my hands...