# Is there yet any way to edit an migrated question on the source site?

Tags: support, tags, edits, migrated-questions

In my occasional check on the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, I encountered [Commenting On a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143045/commenting-on-a-thread?noredirect=1), which has quite rightly been migrated to meta. However, there appears to now be no way to either edit the stub, in order to get rid of the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, or to delete the stub, despite the fact that I have the vote-for-delete priv on SO.

I like [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) to be tidy, and this question is making it messy. [Two years ago, this kind of problem required ♦ moderator action to fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/allow-us-to-edit-tags-on-migrated-questions). Is that still the case? What can be done?

Comment: I also periodically look at `untagged`, so I can either retag or delete (usually delete) any posts there that you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why any edit needs to be done - the migration stubs are deleted automatically [after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79082/133693).

Comment: Are they? [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52703/151211) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @AakashM: See [Why was my question moved, and why was it then deleted off of the original site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082)

Comment: @AakashM - [they are deleted after 30 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79082/133693)

Comment: Cool, I will sit on my hands then :)